# RegEx Removing Span tags from HTML

Tags: html, regex

I need some RegEx for removing span tags with a specific class including the end tag but don't want to remove what's in between ...
I do not want to remove any other span tags

I cannot come up with it since I tend to forget the RegEx Tricks :(

I have this

```
<span class="SpellE">system_user.user_name</span>
<span>This is some text</span>
<Span class="OtherCLass">Some other text</span>
<span class="SpellE">system_user.userid</span>
```

And I want this result

```
system_user.user_name
<span>This is some text</span>
<Span class="OtherCLass">Some other text</span>
system_user.userid
```

Yes I need to tidy up some messy MS Html :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show that you have tried something.  Do you know any regex?  Or are you wanting us to do it all for you?

Comment: Also, what language are you trying to tidy it up with?  PHP?  Javascript? etc

Comment: Don't use a regex, a simple string.replace (depending on your language?) will be much easier to do

Comment: Wouldn't some DOM trick like `[...document.querySelectorAll('span.SpellE')].map(el=>{el.outerHTML = el.innerHTML})` be a more reliable way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex should match what you want:

```
<span class=\"SpellE\">(.*)</span>
```

It matches the span with class='SpellE', creating a Group of the span text.

Then you should replace the match with Group 1.

In JavaScript, you can use it like this:

```
var testStr = '<span class="SpellE">system_user.user_name</span>\n'
    + '<span>This is some text</span>\n'
    + '<Span class="OtherCLass">Some other text</span>\n'
    + '<span class="SpellE">system_user.userid</span>\n';

var regex = /<span class=\"SpellE\">(.*)</span>/gi;

var result = testStr.replace(regex, '\1');
```

Now the result should be your wanted output.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled over this old post... The Javascript solution Poul posted needs a little change to work properly:

```js
var testStr = '<span class="SpellE">system_user.user_name</span>\n'
    + '<span>This is some text</span>\n'
    + '<Span class="OtherCLass">Some other text</span>\n'
    + '<span class="SpellE">system_user.userid</span>\n';

var regex = /<span class="SpellE">([^<]*)<\/span>/gi;

var result = testStr.replace(regex, '$1');
```